# Should magic items which allow to cast spells be considered as material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spell-components, counterspelling

For using Counterspell, a spell needs to contain some kind of component, otherwise it cant be countered.

https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/642086415040294912?lang=en

When casting spells from magical items the spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise. DMG p141.

spells you cast from items can be countered

https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/12/21/does-the-counterspell-work-against-wands/
https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/08/21/is-it-possible-to-counterspell-a-magic-item/

So, does it mean that the magic items are considered as the material components of the spell?

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] and learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more info.

Comment: It sounds like you're really asking if a nearby enemy (or other observer) can tell when someone is casting a spell with an item. Is that right?

Comment: @Mark Wells yes, since it is possible to counter spells from wands, and i cant find any way for them to notice the spell considering the description of the item.

Comment: @Mark Wells I am trying to understand the mechanics- when casting a spell from a staff/wand/ring most of the times there is nothing that expose it yet people counterspell it. what makes it possible other than considering the item itself as a material component?

Comment: _Counterspell_ can be cast "when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell". It doesn't actually say the spell needs to have components; it's just that that's usually how you know a spell is being cast, and therefore that you can counterspell it.

Comment: @Mark Wells but when using subtle spell for example, the spell cant be countered unless it has material component. what makes the casting from items any different than casting using subtle spell?

Comment: Also just want to note that Sageadvice.eu is not Wizards of the Coast's published Sage Advice. It's just someone who aggregates tweets puts them together. Additionally, those tweets are just a snapshot as to how one of the designers would have ruled at the time they typed it and nothing more. They are no longer official or considered official.

Comment: @Kireban Subtle Spell doesn't really prevent anyone from countering the spell; it just lets you cast without V and S components, which obscures the fact that you're casting a spell. They might still notice a material component or arcane focus, just like they might notice that you're doing _something_ with a magic item, but you aren't chanting in Old Elvish and waving your arms.

Answer (score 1):

## It will depend on the mechanics of the item, but the majority are not counterspellable

But to begin, [counterspell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/counterspell)(PHB, 228) does require you to see the casting:

> which you take when you see a creature within 60 feet of you casting a spell

Seeing generally means that you observe the casting of the spell which usually means you've observed the casting.

However, if the item doesn't require any components at all to cast, then there really isn't a way to counterspell it because the casting isn't visible. Generally, they don't as stated in the DMG (141) when talking about casting from items:

> The spell is cast at the lowest possible spell level, doesn't expend any of the user's spell slots, and requires no components, unless the item's description says otherwise.

Comment: is there an example of wand that requires a component which allows foes to notice the spell casting? usually it just says that you cast the spell from it

Comment: I'll have to check, but your question was about items in general. I kept my answer vague and general so that you could apply it to any specific you/your party find.